# asp.net mvc 2 Html.RenderPartial css

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-2

i'm trying to create a button in css using the  tags.

Example Login button

```
     <li class="#">
                   <a href="" target="_self">
                        <span class="menu-left"></span>

                        <span class="menu-mid">   Login   </span>

                        <span class="menu-right"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

The code above works fine, But when i replace the Login (button name) with

```
 <%    Html.RenderPartial("LogOnUserControl"); %>
```

it adds another link tag < a>. Here is what is looks like after replacing the login keyword.

```
     <li class="#">
                   <a href="" target="_self">
                   <span class="menu-left"></span>

                      <span  class="menu-mid"><a href="/Account/LogOn">Log On</a> </span>
                        <span class="menu-right"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

So now we have     link inside a link which messes up the button.

Question:
Is there any work around this problem?  i really want to use the html.renderpartical function.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`Login(buttonName)` might be where your problem is. That most probably generates the anchor tag.

Comment: that's just a comment i left its not a fucntion. and this is whats generating the < a> tag <%    Html.RenderPartial("LogOnUserControl"); %>

Comment: I copied and paste from your code.. Unless you re-edited it. Anyways check maybe that was part of the default asp generated code.